# Force UIView below navigation bar using Autolayout

Tags: ios7, uiview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, autolayout

In viewDidLoad I am programatically creating a UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling, adding it to controller's view and then setting constraint to push it below the navigation bar. But its not working, what am I missing (my autolayout knowledge is weak, so there might be multiple things I might be missing). Below is the code :

```
    UIScrollView *scrollingView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 40)];
    self.scrollingView = scrollingThumbsScrubber;
    self.scrollingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollingView];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {

        [self.scrollingView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
        id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (scrollingView, topGuide);


        [self.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[topGuide]-20-[scrollingView]"
                                                 options: 0
                                                 metrics: nil
                                                   views: viewsDictionary]
         ];
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever found out how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

What error is actually occurring?

Simply calling

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollingView];
```

and erasing all the code after that should automatically put the scroll view below the navigation bar

Comment: Well it's coming behind the navigation bar if I simply add it.